# New NextJS React project, can't start localhost "Compiled /not-found in 1080ms"

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Started a new installation of NextJS and I am unable to start up localhost, I keep getting 'Compiled /not-found in 1080ms (387 modules) whenever I try to reload the project. Has anyone encountered this before? Angular dev trying to learn React and I can't even get past this hump lol. I haven't changed anything in the project either.

- Things i've tried:

  - I have re-install npm
  - Deleted .next folder
  - Reinstalled the project and created new one
  - Moved to different file locations

[Link To Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J31LS.png)

[Project Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlFaN.png)

Comment: What is your Next.js and Node.js versions?

Comment: @RobinThomas Next is Latest - 13.5.3
node js - 16.3.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to have two different `app` directories:

- `app`
- `src/app`

Both of them will not work together. Next.js do not even create both these directories on a fresh install.

So to resolve this, delete the `app` directory and keep the `src/app` directory.

---

On a side note, you need to update your Node.js version to atleast `16.14`. Anything below that is not supported by Next.js (since you are using `16.3`).

> System Requirements:
>
> - Node.js 16.14 or later.
> - macOS, Windows (including WSL), and Linux are supported.
>
> https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/installation

Comment: I tried that and it still is not working, do I need to recreate the project or anything? Thanks.

Comment: I do not have a file `not-found.tsx`, it did not come initialized in the basic nextjs installation. I reinstalled node and I am currently using that version and I am getting the same error. I included in the description of post a link to the projects hierarchy.

Comment: @JacobBennett Updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: that fixed it.. I didn't add that.. that's so weird. Thank you very much man. Have a good evening.

Comment: somehow a rouge app/ dir got added to my project and this helped me a ton, thank you